# MATLAB 'Help on Selection' for Local Functions

Tags: matlab

Consider the function file `F_Main.m` with one main function and one [local function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html). Both functions contain one [help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html) line each.

```
function F_Main()
% Help for F_Main

fprintf( '\n In F_Main(): F_Local() = %d \n', F_Local() );

end

function d = F_Local()
% Help for F_Local

d = 1;

end
```

In the Command Window, the help can be shown with

```
>> help F_Main
  Help for F_Main
>> help F_Main>F_Local
  Help for F_Local
```

However, this question is about [Help on Selection](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/help-resources.html) in the Editor, accessible via a right mouse click on the function name. It is shown correctly for the main function, but it cannot be found for local functions:

[image: Current Folder Details Panel and Command Window]

[image: Editor Help on Selection - Main Function]

[image: Editor Help on Selection - Local Function]

Can MATLAB be configured such that help is shown in a pop-up window for local functions as well, if one uses the **'Help on Selection' method in the file containing said local function**?

Comment: `F_local` is not a function you can access from outside `F_main`, so there is no need for help for it. It is a function that only exists inside `F_main`. If you can access the line that calls `F_local`, then you are in the same file where the function is defined, thus you can go and read it. instead of opening a new window. If you are not in the file, then you should not have access to the function, as you may have multiple local fucntion in different files. E.g. most of my functions have a "parse_inputs"  local, all of them different, as they are algorithm-specific. This seems bydesing.

Comment: You can access them because you specifically state that its a local function `F_main>F_local`. Im not saying you are wrong, ultimately this is a style choice. Im just saying that this seems to be very embedded in the core of the MATLAB editor and that it is like this probably by design. How many local functions are in the tens of toolboxes in MATLAB? They probably did this to avoid possible confusions

Comment: @AnderBiguri But you can access the help of local functions even from outside via `>> help F_Main>F_Local`. For me, there is no difference between navigating to the help of a local function or to the help of a different main function in a different file. Both methods force me to jump away from the current line. With 'Help on Selection', however, I can see the help without having to go off screen - at least for the main function. Hence my question for local functions. Besides, I would access the 'Help on Selection' from within that file, so that there is no ambiguity wich function to look for.

Comment: I see your point, I just dont think you can. Perhaps with some incredibly obscure java-based undocumented feature that "hacks" the help functionality, who knows.

Comment: @AnderBiguri You are probably right. For me, it seems like it might be a nice feature, but I do not have very much hope.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I personally do not use local functions very often, and perhaps unawarely this is one of the reasons.